# Implementing with only NOR gates

Tags: power, digital-logic, nand

I have an equation

> y = ab + cb'

How would I implement this with only NOR Gates?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried distributing the ab, but i'm not getting anywhere lol

Comment: So did the linked question help you solve your problem?

Comment: `i'm not getting anywhere` is not a description of what you tried ..... please show your work (add it to the question)